# How to fetch data after a particular time interval while using rxjs observables in angular for dynamic data from api

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I am trying to fetch data from an api and update it dynamically in my angular application using RxJs Observables, The problem with my code is that the api which I am using has a limit on the number of requests that can be made per hour. how can I modify my service and component in such a way that the data is dynamically fetched and updated after a particular time  for eg. 5 minutes?

**Service Code:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from "rxjs/operators";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiserviceService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  private _refreshreq = new Subject<void>();

  get refresh(){
    return this._refreshreq;
  }
  getfng(): Observable<object>{
    return this.http.get('https://api.testapi.com/fng/').pipe(
      tap(()=>{
        this.refresh.next();
      })
    )
  }
  getcdata() : Observable<object>{
    return this.http.get('https://api.testapi.com/v2/data/').pipe(
      tap(()=>{
        this.refresh.next();
      })
    )
  }
}
```

**Component code:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ApiserviceService } from '../services/apiservice.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-homecomponent',
  templateUrl: './homecomponent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./homecomponent.component.css']
})
export class HomecomponentComponent implements OnInit {
  fngdata: any;
  value: any;
  class: any;
  datarray: any;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getfngindex();
    this.getdata();
    this.service.refresh.subscribe(response=>{
      this.getfngindex();
      this.getdata();
    })
  }
  constructor(private service: ApiserviceService) { }
  getfngindex(){
    return this.service.getfng().subscribe((data:any)=>{
      this.fngdata = data.data[0]
      console.log(this.fngdata);

      this.value =this.fngdata.value
      this.class =this.fngdata.value_classification
    })
  }
  getdata(){
    return this.service.getcdata().subscribe((data:any)=>{
      this.datarray = data.data;
      console.log(this.datarray[0]);
    })
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

When calling an observable you could simply use the `repeat` operator with the given delay option.

So for example in your `getdata` method you could simply do the following:

```
const FIVE_MINUTES_MS =  5 * 60 * 1_000;

this.service.getcdata()
  .pipe(
    repeat({ delay: FIVE_MINUTES_MS })
  )
  .subscribe((data:any) => {
    this.datarray = data.data;
      console.log(this.datarray[0]);
  })
```

This will trigger indefinitely, but if you want to limit the number of calls you could also set a count property

You can find more about `repeat` [here](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/repeat)

Answer (score 0):

I made the following changes in the Component ts file's ngOnInit() code to get the functionality I wanted:

**Component Code:**

```
import { interval } from 'rxjs';
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getfngindex();
    this.getdata();
    const datatimelimit = interval(60000) //fetches and updates the data after every 1 minute
    const fngtimelimit = interval(4*60*60*1000) //fetches and updates the data after every 4 hours
    datatimelimit.subscribe(response=>{
      this.getdata();
    })
    fngtimelimit.subscribe(response=>{
      this.getfngindex();
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may start the 'begin' of the interval after the completion of each call, maybe this following can help you :

```
import { finalize, debounce } from 'rxjs';

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getfngindex(0);
    this.getdata(0);
}

constructor(private service: ApiserviceService) { }

getfngindex(waitingTime: number) {
    return this.service.getfng().pipe(
        debounceTime(waitingTime),
        finalize(() => this.getfngindex(4 * 60 * 60 * 1000))
    ).subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.fngdata = data.data[0]
        console.log(this.fngdata);

        this.value = this.fngdata.value
        this.class = this.fngdata.value_classification
    })
}

getdata(waitingTime: number) {
    return this.service.getfng().pipe(
        debounceTime(waitingTime),
        finalize(() => this.getfngindex(60000))
    ).subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.datarray = data.data;
        console.log(this.datarray[0]);
    })
}
```

According to me the issue with interval it's we're spamming the API (we have to be cautious if it's API with a freemium plan) : the next call can be triggered where as the previous one is not finish yet.

Thanks to `debounce` operator the observable will be triggered after XX millseconds (0 when it's the init). With `finalize` operator the cooldown restart in order to trigger the next request (even if it's error).

Like this we're sure that the cooldown of each request restart after the response of API. In this example becareful because the `this.refresh.next()` be call before the `debounce` is finish. But the idea is here :)